# Same Random int Generation In For Loop

Tags: java

Im studying OOP right now and trying to create student notes and students id's randomly. Then I want to store them in Student array. However, in the following code, while im getting different ids, the student notes are all same "0" or "1" everytime I re-run the console. I checked my code but couldn't find a error on my code. If im missing something, can someone explain me please?

(I edited my post. Sory for late.)

```
        public class StudentTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Student [] allStudents = new Student[100];
            Random r = new Random();
            int randomId;
            int randomNot;
   
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                randomId = r.nextInt(100)+5000;
                randomNot = r.nextInt(101);
                Student newStudent = new Student(randomId,randomNot);
                allStudents[i]= newStudent;
            }
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            allStudents[i].printStudents();
        }
    
    }
    
    //MY CLASS 

    public class Student {
    private int id;
    private int not;

    public Student(int id, int not) {
        this.id = id;
        this.not = not;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getNot() {
        return not;
    }

    public void setNot(int not) {
        this.not = not;
    }

    public void printStudents(){
        System.out.println("ID: " + this.id + " NOT: " + this.not);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: Thank you. Im going to put my all codes here. Just i didnt want to make it too long and hard to check. Sory.

Comment: Show us `Student`. Else this is an exercise in pure speculation.

Comment: If all the students end up with the same `not` value, I bet that the `not` field is declared `static`. Don't do that!!!

Comment: I edited my post and put my class and main class here.

Comment: @Progman sory for Turkish words. I actually changed all my code to english for your understanding but missed that part. Its a method for printing students.

Comment: Edited the mistakes. This is my early stage at stackoverflow and kinda stressed out while im trying to put my code here. So i missed some Turkish parts when i was translating for you guys.

Comment: @yasofiso The problem is not reproducible with the code you have added to your question. It generates the `id` and `not` values randomly for each individual `Student` object. They don't have all the same `id` or `not`, but some of them *can* have the same value, depending on the values returned by the `Random` instance.

Comment: @Progman Thank you for interested in my code and problem. And thank you for your answer. Am i going to get banned for miss editing my code and lack of info ? I will try to be more careful when posting my questions.

Comment: @yasofiso You don't get banned from stackoverflow when you miss information about your question. But to help with this particular problem you have to provide a [mcve] which clearly shows the problem you have. Also [edit] your question to include the output you get when you run your code on your system. Currently, this code works fine as expected.